# Merging touching polygons in same layer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, dissolve, aggregation

I have a shapefile consisting of many polygons, and I would like to merge them when they touch each other (see red lines below).

[image]

I've been trying quite a few tools in ArcMap 10.7 such as Dissolve, but they don't seem to do what I want exactly. The Aggregate Polygons in the coverage toolbox pops up in my search, but I can't actually click the toolbox, perhaps I don't have access to this in ArcMap.

Alternatively, I'd be content if I could merge all polygons separated by <1000m (in the example picture, all 'cells' are 1 square kilometers, so in this case I would end up with one large polygon except for the two blocks in the top-left), which I tried to do with the Aggregate Polygon tool in the Cartography toolbox, but the output shapefile is identical to the input.

Comment: there's no field by which to dissolve, so then it'd just dissolve everything into one massive polygon, regardless of the distance between them, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: If you are also looking for an R solution then please ask about that in a separate question so that this one stays focused on ArcMap.

Comment: Ok, thank you polygeo. Furthermore, BERA, thanks but I don't think dissolve is the way to go, as I am not dissolving based on anything in the attribute table, so when multi_part is false, the dissolve function does not actually do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Intersect the grid with itself, output type POINT
2. Buffer the points with a small distance, I use 10 m for a 100 km grid
3. Merge input grid with buffers
4. Now the adjacent polygons are connected where the corners meet. Dissolve without multipart

[image]

Comment: This works BERA, thanks a lot! What is the rationale behind this solution? Is it that Arcmap doesn't recognize polygons as adjacent when they share a single node so there is need for a somewhat larger buffer, or is there something else to it?

Comment: I dont know why, but ArcMap doesnt dissolve polygons only touching at one corner.